# OSGi bundle start order linux vs windows

Tags: windows, linux, osgi, equinox

I am currently deploying a number of bundles into equnox using pax-runner.  The bundles are in a folder, the path to this is passed to runner in an args file.  The problem I have is that the same deployment of bundles are started in a different order in windows than in linux.  In windows everything is fine, however in linux the bundles appear to be started in a random order.  The result of this is that some bundles are stated in the wrong order which causes errors, e.g jersey-server gets started before jersey-core so I getr a NPE.  Can anyone provide an explanation as to why this happens?  Do I need to specify a start order for certain bundles?

Comment: Is there a programming related question here?

Comment: Not directly.  I'm trying to ascertain why, when deploying two identical sets of OSGi bundles in an equinox container, the start order appears to be differenton linux as opposed to windows.

Answer (score 3):

We just scan the directory for bundles so why the random order I cannot say. But for sure you should not rely on that order. OSGi best practices says that you should not rely on start order at all but if you cannot leave without you will have to use different means for specifying the start order. Fo example you could put bundles in different folders per start order to and specify the start order per configured directory.

Comment: I ended up creating a scan-file with start-level specified for certain bundles and this resolved it.  Thanks.

Comment: You'd better make the start order based on the dependency. And OSGi has start level service to control the starting order of bundles.